# How to graph values measured at different intervals?

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2013

I have a table of values measured in time, but the time intervals between consecutive values are not the same. It looks like this:

```
time (in days)   value
179.948          9.89
230.869          10.1
236.956          10.11
```

I want to graph this in such a way that time is linear on the chart (the first value in the example is far away in time from the other two that are relatively close to each other).

How can I accomplish this in MS Excel 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Scatter chart (with or without Lines) may be easiest because it plots numeric values on both axes, so no chance of what looks like a number being interpreted as a text and so spaced equally with others, rather than according to its value:

[image: SO25922023 example]

Answer (score -1):

Seems that you want a graphic not so scattered. And you can make it by several ways, and now I can figure out 2 of them:

1. Group data. You can group several values in a range (ex: [0,50[,[50,100[, etc) and then make a graphic of it (bars, pie, etc).
2. Scale the data. Applying a function over any variable (like a logaritmic one) can change the "distance" between values.

Hope this helps to achieve your objetives.